# Redefinition with a different type

Tags: ios

I'm having trouble with this block of code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < [tempInviteeArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *tempContact = [tempInviteeArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *tempContactDictionary = [tempContact objectAtIndex:1];
        int tempContactDelay = [[tempContact objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

        FlokContact *tempContact = [[FlokContact alloc] initWithJSONData:tempContactDictionary andDelay:tempContactDelay];


    }
```

That last line throws an error:

```
 "Redefinition of 'tempContact' with a different type
```

initWithJSONData: accepts NSDictionary
andDelay: int

I've tried to rewrite this code, with different types and all, 
I'm just not sure what I'm doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already declared a variable in this scope named `tempContact` (`NSArray *tempContact...`). Change the name of one of them.

Comment: It's the easy mistakes that really get you

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *tempContact and FlokContact *tempContact have the same name, that's the problem.

Change **FlokContact *tempContact to FlokContact *temp_Contact** or what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [tempInviteeArray count]; i++)
{
NSArray *tempContact = [tempInviteeArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSDictionary *tempContactDictionary = [tempContact objectAtIndex:1];
int tempContactDelay = [[tempContact objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
  {

 FlokContact *tempContact = [[FlokContact alloc] initWithJSONData:tempContactDictionary andDelay:tempContactDelay];

  }

}
```