# Redefinition of variable error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use the other code in my app. But in some lines I have got such error:

```
Redefinition of "some_variable_name" error
```

For instance,

```
struct some_struct {double t0, t1;};
```

How to fix this issue? This is the one initialization of this struct over the all code. But I got this.
How to fix it?

Comment: i think you already define "some_variable_name" variable....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088043/redefinition-of-variable-with-different-type-ios-development and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314564/redefinition-with-a-different-type

Comment: I'm looking all over the project. Nothing except this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you're including you're headers multiple times? tough to say without more details.

Try wrapping your code around this

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H 

#endif
```

These are called [Include Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and prevent the code from being included again and thus the double declarations of identifiers.